# how to know the type of reference referring to a object in java?

Tags: java

```
 package example;
    class Machine
    {
        public void start()
       {
            System.out.println("MACHINE IS STARTING");
       }
    }
    class Camera extends Machine
    {
        public void snap()
        {
            System.out.println("SNAP");
        }
    }

    public class App {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            Camera cam1 = new Camera();
            Machine mach1 = cam1; 

        }

    }
```

in the above code camera object is being refereed by both cam1 which is of
    type Camera and mach1 of type Machine .
            Is there any function which can tell the type of references that are being referred to that object???

Comment: No. [filler to make this comment 15 characters long]

Comment: Can you tell us more about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes. You can use `instanceof`. That said, it's not OO to use `instanceof` :)

Comment: Just to clear up one thing: references have no type; *objects* do, and *variables* do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know the class of the instance referenced by the `mach1` variable, use :

```
mach1.getClass().getName()
```

If you want to test if `mach1` is of a specific type, use `instanceof`

```
if (mach1 instanceof Camera)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getclass method for it

```
java.lang.Object.getClass()

mach1.getClass().getName()
```

it will return the runtime class of an object.